# Conky Issues: previous wallpaper or application background, double text, old conky text overlap

Tags: ubuntu, conky

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, having multiple issues with my Conky setup.

**First**, I use Variety, changing wallpaper application. Now Conky takes the snap of the earliest wallpaper background and uses it till next restart. The same issue with any application also.

**Second**, the dynamic expressions like top processes or data consumption overlap with the previous value i.e. the old value doesn't get cleaned.

**Third**, my Conky texts are leaving black duplicates with a vertical offset, it seems like I'm running two Conky.

Tried purging and reinstalling Conky but no use.

My **conky.conf**

```
-- vim: ts=4 sw=4 noet ai cindent syntax=lua
--[[
Conky, a system monitor, based on torsmo

Any original torsmo code is licensed under the BSD license

All code written since the fork of torsmo is licensed under the GPL

Please see COPYING for details

Copyright (c) 2004, Hannu Saransaari and Lauri Hakkarainen
Copyright (c) 2005-2012 Brenden Matthews, Philip Kovacs, et. al. (see AUTHORS)
All rights reserved.

This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.
You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
]]

conky.config = {
    alignment = 'top_left',
    background = false,
    border_width = 0,
    cpu_avg_samples = 2,
    own_window_transparent = true,
    own_window = true,
    default_color = '#7f77e6',
    color1 = 'yellow',
    color2 = '#0cc99d',
    color3 = '#cc6452',
    color4 = '#ac5fba',
    default_outline_color = 'black',
    default_shade_color = 'white',
    draw_borders = false,
    draw_graph_borders = true,
    draw_outline = true,
    draw_shades = false,
    use_xft = true,
    font = 'LCDMono:size=8',
    gap_x = 5,
    gap_y = 30,
    minimum_height = 5,
    minimum_width = 5,
    net_avg_samples = 2,
    no_buffers = true,
    out_to_console = false,
    out_to_stderr = false,
    extra_newline = false,
    own_window = true,
    own_window_class = 'Conky',
    own_window_type = 'desktop',
    stippled_borders = 0,
    update_interval = 1.0,
    uppercase = false,
    use_spacer = 'none',
    show_graph_scale = false,
    show_graph_range = false,

}

conky.text = [[
${alignc}${color red}${font LCDMono:bold:size=8}IP: ${exec curl -s www.icanhazip.com}
${alignc}${color red}${font LCDMono:bold:size=8}WIFI IP: ${addr wlp1s0}
${alignc}${color red}${font LCDMono:bold:size=8}ETHN IP: ${addr enp2s0}
${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}Uptime${font}:$color1 $uptime
${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}Frequency (in MHz)${font}:$color1 $freq
${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}Frequency (in GHz)${font}:$color1 $freq_g
${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}RAM Usage${font}:$color1 $mem/$memmax - $memperc% $color2${membar 4}
${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}Swap Usage${font}:$color1 $swap/$swapmax - $swapperc% $color2${swapbar 4}
${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}CPU Usage${font}:$color1 $cpu% $color2${cpubar 4}
${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}Processes${font}:$color1 $processes  ${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}Running${font}:$color1 $running_processes
${color2}$hr
${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}File systems:${font}
 $color1/${fs_used /}/${fs_size /}$color2 ${fs_bar 6 /}
${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}Networking WIFI:${font}
${color3}Up:$color2 ${upspeed wlp1s0} ${color3} - Down:$color2 ${downspeed wlp1s0}
${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}Networking EHERNET:${font}
${color3}Up:$color2 ${upspeed enp2s0} ${color3} - Down:$color2 ${downspeed enp2s0}
${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}Networking BLUETOOTH:${font}
${color3}Up:$color2 ${upspeed bnep0} ${color3} - Down:$color2 ${downspeed bnep0}
${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}Networking VMNET1:${font}
${color3}Up:$color2 ${upspeed vmnet1} ${color3} - Down:$color2 ${downspeed vmnet1}
${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}Networking VMNET8:${font}
${color3}Up:$color2 ${upspeed vmnet8} ${color3} - Down:$color2 ${downspeed vmnet8}
${color2}$hr
${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}Name${goto 100} PID    CPU%    MEM%${font}
 ${color3} ${top name 1}${goto 100} $color2${top pid 1} ${top cpu 1} ${top mem 1}
 ${color3} ${top name 2}${goto 100} $color2${top pid 2} ${top cpu 2} ${top mem 2}
 ${color3} ${top name 3}${goto 100} $color2${top pid 3} ${top cpu 3} ${top mem 3}
 ${color3} ${top name 4}${goto 100} $color2${top pid 4} ${top cpu 4} ${top mem 4}
${color2}$hr
${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}Total Data Consumption${font}
 ${color4}Down: ${color green}${totaldown wlp1s0} ${goto 100}${color4}  Up: ${color green}${totalup wlp1s0}
${color}${font LCDMono:size=8}Today's Data Consumption${font}
 ${color1}${font LCDMono:size=6}WIFI:${font} 
    ${color4}Down: ${color green}${execi 60 LC_ALL=C vnstat | grep -A 4 wlp1s0 | grep "today" | awk '{print  $2 $3}'}${color4}  Up: ${color green}${execi 60 LC_ALL=C vnstat | grep -A 4 wlp1s0 | grep "today" | awk '{print  $5 $6}'}${color4}  Total: ${color green}${execi 60 LC_ALL=C vnstat | grep -A 4 wlp1s0 | grep "today" | awk '{print  $8 $9}'}
 ${color1}${font LCDMono:size=6}ETHN:${font} 
    ${color4}Down: ${color green}${execi 60 LC_ALL=C vnstat | grep -A 4 enp2s0 | grep "today" | awk '{print  $2 $3}'}${color4}  Up: ${color green}${execi 60 LC_ALL=C vnstat | grep -A 4 enp2s0 | grep "today" | awk '{print  $5 $6}'}${color4}  Total: ${color green}${execi 60 LC_ALL=C vnstat | grep -A 4 enp2s0 | grep "today" | awk '{print  $8 $9}'}
${color2}$hr
${color green}${font LCDMono:size=6}WIFI Down${alignr}WIFI Up${font}
${color2}${downspeedgraph wlp1s0 15, 120 00B706 FF0000 -t}${alignr}${upspeedgraph wlp1s0 15, 120 00AFB7 FF0000 -t}
${color green}${font LCDMono:size=6}ETHER Down${alignr}ETHER Up${font}
${color2}${downspeedgraph enp2s0 15, 120 00B706 FF0000 -t}${alignr}${upspeedgraph enp2s0 15, 120 00AFB7 FF0000 -t}
${color green}${font LCDMono:size=6}CPU1${goto 60}CPU2${goto 120}CPU3${goto 180}CPU4${font}
${color2}${cpugraph cpu1 15, 60 00B706 FF0000 -t}${cpugraph cpu2 15, 60 00AFB7 FF0000 -t}${cpugraph cpu3 15, 60 00AFB7 FF0000 -t}${cpugraph cpu4 15, 60 00AFB7 FF0000 -t}
${alignc}${color red}${font LCDMono:bold:size=14}You are under watch

]]
```

Comment: If you haven't already done so, run `ps -C conky` in a terminal and make sure that you're not running two Conky instances.

Comment: 4047 tty2     00:14:56 conky
16974 tty2     00:00:00 conky
 okay yeah, there are, I missed that. but why it is happenning?

Comment: Well, I just figured out that I should use conky -d to start the daemon, now I see only one process running, but the issue persists. But the extent of overlap is less. When I use conky own window transperant true, there I see the black offset text, but when it is false cant see it cause it mixes up with the black background, but I can see two graphs in opaqe background cause the graph color is not black in the duplicate text.